# Modify JSON Object in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, bots, discord.js

I'm programming a Discord Bot which should have a list of messages that users can modify. For example:
`--remove <Message Text>` 
Would remove the specified message from the JSON Object in a file called `messages.json`.

## JSON File

The JSON Obkect is structured like this:

```
{
  "<Channel Id>": ['<Message Text 1>', '<Message Text 2>']
}
```

## Details

I'm using [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/) and [node.js](https://nodejs.org). The bot's code is stored inside a Github repository and the bot itself is hosted on [heroku.com](https://heroku.com).

## Issue

I can't for the life of me figure out how to access the `messages.json` file and modify the array associated with the Channel Id.

Comment: Use file system `fs` library. [This should be helpful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lJhX6PGmMw).

Comment: Use [fs.writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) like vrecusko20 suggested and [simple-git](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git) to update git repo,